# Java: Split strings and put them into text area's

Tags: java, swing

I have a method that saves a name and their score into a text file. Now I made a button 'high scores', invoking a method that reads from the high scores that text file. For now the output of this is very ugly, so I want to put the names in one text area and the scores into another text area so they are evenly separated.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

My current output:[image: Current output]

Comment: why a `JTextArea`? I think using `JLabel`s in combination with appropriate layout managers would get you what you want (e.g. `FlowLayout` with nested components using `BoxLayout`). Also, please include an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: it's quite hard to tell what you're actually asking. please try to boil down your problem to its essence, then ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format of the file is like this:

> NAME;SCORE\n
>   OTHERNAME;OTHERSCORE\n
>   ...

You could do something like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(...); // Initialize a buffered reader reading from that text file.
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine() != null) {
    String name = line.split(";")[0];
    String score = line.split(";")[1];
    namesTextArea.append(name + "\n");
    scoresTextArea.append(score + "\n");
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is a way to handle the alignment of your names and scores. You can use Java's support for [format strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to automatically pad the *name* field and give it a maximum width, thus aligning all of your scores in the same column:

```
String.format("%-20.20s %s", "Name", "Score")
```

This will pad each name to make it 20 characters wide, and also truncate the name if it's more than 20 characters so that it doesn't overflow into the score's area. You can change `20` above to whatever width you think is reasonable.